# ServiceLocator get instance by passing construction parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container, service-locator

How can I get object instance with service locator with the constructor below. `ProductCode` is the constructor parameter used to initialize member properties. For all other constructor parameters, I have registered them using unity in the `global.asax` file.

Basic way to get object instance if constructor parameters are reference type:

```
var productSettingsRepo = 
      ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ProductSettingsRepository>();

public ProductSettingsRepository(ILogWriter logWriter, 
          ISecurityFunctionRepository securityRepo,
          IProductSettingsManager productSettingsManager,
          IReferenceDataService referenceDataService, 
          string productCode)
      {
          _logWriter = logWriter;
          _securityRepo = securityRepo;
          _productSettingsManager = productSettingsManager;
          _referenceDataService = referenceDataService;
          ProductInfo = GetProductData(productCode);
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

The Service Locator pattern [is considered an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html),  you might want to refactor to use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Having said that, here is one way you can fix your problem without refactoring:

Create a factory interface and class that depends on the service locator to create a `ProductSettingsRepository` class given the product code like this:

```
public interface IProductSettingsRepositoryFactory
{
    ProductSettingsRepository Create(string productCode);
}

public class ProductSettingsRepositoryFactory : IProductSettingsRepositoryFactory
{
    public ProductSettingsRepository Create(string productCode)
    {
        return new ProductSettingsRepository(
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogWriter>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISecurityFunctionRepository>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IProductSettingsManager>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IReferenceDataService>(),
            productCode);
    }
}
```

Then make sure that you register this factory with the unity container like this:

```
unity_container
   .RegisterType<IProductSettingsRepositoryFactory, ProductSettingsRepositoryFactory>();
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
var factory = ServiceLocator
                   .Current
                   .GetInstance<IProductSettingsRepositoryFactory>();

var productSettingsRepo = factory.Create("my product code");
```

Comment: There's appropriate places for Service Locator pattern.  The example you linked is a good example of where the service locator pattern is inappropriate.  That does not make it universally an anti-pattern.  Just about every good pattern has potential to be applied in scenarios where it is inappropriate.  Part of being a good architect is understanding where patterns are appropriately applied. +1 for putting your opinion aside and helping with a solution.

Comment: @AaronLS, Thanks. The only case where I think that the Service Locator might be appropriate is when working with legacy code and refactoring to Dependency Injection is very expensive (objects are being constructed from all over the place). Can you give me another example (for new applications) where it can be a good pattern?

Comment: Often many dependencies would only have one concrete implementation, and the goal may only be to simplify dependency resolution instead rather than decouple the concrete implementation.  Regardless of the goal, decoupling or simplified dependency injection:  You may want to be explicit in retrieving a dependency procedurally at a certain step within a process, or even conditionally, in which case you are not wanting it injected automatically into a constructor or property, but instead want to explicitly locate the service in a specific scenario.

Comment: If you do need to use the service locator pattern and support multiple concrete implementations, a strategy pattern will work. This might be used where you need to conditionally decide when/how to leverage a service on-demand, and also need configuration driven decision of which concrete implementation to leverage. E.g. a site that supports paying with a combination of payment processors can retrieve and call services on demand. Often the strategy pattern looks like a service locator pattern that retrieves multiple instances instead of one(all the concrete implementations of that service).

Comment: @AaronLS, even if you have a single implementation, in the future you might have more. If you want to be explicit in retrieving the dependency (control the process of retrieving it), you can use an abstract factory. The advantage would be that you neither [hide the dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) nor [limit the composability of your classes](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).