# Passing key to ServiceLocator from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am building a server manager application that displays list of servers.
Each server provides some information which is arranged and grouped into 4 different windows.User can open any window from server's context menu.
windows are opened and managed by ViewManager class which listens to different messages(via. messenger).
I am using server ip as key for each instance in ServiceLocator.
This way i can easily manage ViewModel instances of same type.

Problem I am facing is,
how can i pass key to GetInstance() at runtime so that when window is initialized it uses the viewmodel with the specified key?

Currently i am using a static string variable(key) which i declared in ViewModelLocator.I initialize it with server's ip before instantiating window.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you provide some code of your ViewModelLocator and so on?

Comment: @FranzWimmer Its the default ViewModelLocator .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721678/servicelocator-get-instance-by-passing-construction-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721678/servicelocator-get-instance-by-passing-construction-parameter)

Comment: @LionelPire how is this duplicate?

Comment: It means that the post I linked might answer your question since it's really similar

Comment: @LionelPire well it isn't.the link you posted talks about passing parameter to constructor of registered type and not to GetInstance().anyways thanks for the time you spend.

Comment: Maybe this will answer you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795596/how-to-use-mvvmlight-simpleioc if this doesn't please rephrase your questions as I don't really understand

Comment: @LionelPire I will rephrase the question as soon as i reach home.If you have a look at accepted answer in the link you gave,the second point has a code "SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());".here, new key is generated everytime i call GetInstance().I have a unique key and i want to use that instead of New Guid.my question is how can i pass that key to locator?

Comment: Well there is your answer : call explicitely SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>(myIP); whenever you need to do it at runtime

Comment: @LionelPire view creates the viewmodel.how can i tell the view that it is supposed to use the viewmodel with key  "myip"?